# Re-calling react hook "useEffect" problem

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect

I am working on a new small project in React and I am using React hooks. The ultimate target of this app is to fetch the data of the weather of a certain city from openweather API and display it on the screen. I have created a custom hook to fetch the data from the endpoint and passed in three arguments as shown below :

```
export const useHttp = (baseURL, dependancies, isSubmit) => {

    // Inizialize isLoading to false 
    const [isLoading, setLoading] = useState(false);

    // Initialize the fetched data to an empty string
    const [fetchedData, setFetchedData] = useState('');

    useEffect(() => {
        /*Check if isSubmit is true before fetching the corresponding 
        data*/
        if (isSubmit) {

            // set isLoading to true until we get the data
            setLoading(true);

            // Start fetching the data from the url received
            fetch(baseURL)
                .then(response => {
                    if (!response.ok) {
                        throw new Error('Failed to fetch. ');
                    }
                    return response.json();
                })
                // Return the data when fetched successfully
                .then(data => {
                    setLoading(false);
                    setFetchedData(data);
                })
                /*Show an alert when fetching encounters an error and stop the 
                loader accordingly*/
                .catch(err => {
                    alert("Please insert a valid name")
                    setLoading(false);
                })
        }
    }, dependancies)
    // Returning the data to use them later in displaying the weather
    return [isLoading, fetchedData];
};
```

And here is how my form component works :

```
 // initialized the input to an empty string
    const [searchTerm, setSearchTerm] = useState('');

    // Initialize the state of submit to false 
    const [isSubmit, setIsSubmit] = useState(false);

    // Use array destruction to get isLoading and fetchedData from the imported userHttp hook
    const [isLoading, fetchedData] = useHttp(`http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${searchTerm}
    &APPID=b8c1572d189de60f5480324c6b53d9ab`, [isSubmit], isSubmit);

    // Use object destruction to get the desired properties out of the fetched data
    const { name, sys, weather, main } = fetchedData ? fetchedData : '';

    // Get the user input in the search bar to pass it to submitInput function
    const getSearchTerm = (e) => {
        setSearchTerm(e.target.value);
    }

    // Submit the userinput and call the custom hook to fetch the data matched with the input
    const submitInput = (event) => {
        // Prevent the form from actually submitting
        event.preventDefault();
        // Change the state of isSubmit so that useEffect can be re-called
        setIsSubmit(!isSubmit);
    }
```

As you can see, I wanted to change the value of the state "isSubmit" whenever the user submits in order to recall useEffect as "isSubmit" is also passed as a dependency. Moreover, I created a condition to prevent useEffect from working whenever the app is rendered because I want it to work only when the user submits.

The thing is, it works perfectly the first time but when I enter another value, I have to click twice on the button to make it work. I spent a while thinking about this issue but I came to nothing in the end. Hopefully, someone can help me with this. Thanks in advance.

Here is also a link to the project rep on GitHub : 
https://github.com/Saifsamirk/weatherApp

Answer (score 1):

Your `useEffect` hook only fires when `isSubmit = true`. When you call `submitInput` you only change the value of `isSubmit` to `!isSubmit`. It will only be `true` every second time. You might wanna reset your `isSubmit` state to false after firing the event.

Comment: Thanks for your response. It works now but the thing is, I used this condition to prevent useEffect from working whenever the app is rendered and make it work only when the user submits. Now it already shows a result before I even insert an input.

Comment: @Saif i updated my answer, if you want to keep your condition in useEffect, you should reset you state to false before the event. Maybe when the user starts typing, or maybe at the beginning of your ```submitInput``` function

Comment: It means I have to set isSubmit to false in submitInput ?!

Comment: @Saif having an other look at your code, the best place would probably be when the fetch request is finished. after ```setLoading(false)``` you should do ```setIsSubmit(false)``` too.

Comment: This might not be possible as I am using it as an argument too in useHttp hook. Also, I am initializing the state of isSubmit in the form not in the useHttp hook which is in a different file.

Comment: Ok, here's an idea: why not keep the ```isSubmit``` state in the useHttp hook aswell, and you can return it's value and setter from there ```return [isLoading, isSubmit, setIsSubmit, fetchedData]```.

Comment: That seems to be good. Yet, when I use "useHttp" hook in the form, I am using already isSubmit and this can't be done before initialization.